# How to return the sum of an array if an object or objects exist across multiple columns

Tags: excel

Here is my problem:

I need to search using or logic in a 2d array for any row that contains any given substring(s), and sum that row's sum column as a result.

I have a column, Hours, that I would like to sum if the column Name OR the column Description contain any number of criteria. So far my (ugly) solution is (pardon the formatting):

```
SUM(SUMIFS(B16:B100,C16:C100,{"(asterisk)Crit1(asterisk)","(asterisk)Crit2(asterisk)"}),SUMIFS(B16:B100,D16:D100,{"(asterisk)Crit1(asterisk)","(asterisk)Crit2(asterisk)"}))
```

This by itself is not bad, and with only 2 columns isn't horrible. But, some of you may have seen that this can cause double-counts if the criteria is in both columns, which I do not want.

So my question: Can I do this in such a way where I can search for criteria in multiple columns, and if they exist in any column, then sum the sum range, only once?

Comment: Sample data would help visitors to understand your expection.

Answer (score 0):

Try (*untested since you show no data*):

```
=SUM(B16:B100*((ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Crit1","Crit2"},C16:C100))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"crit3","Crit4"},D16:D100)))>0))
```

Adding comparisons is like doing an `OR`; by comparing the sum of the comparisons to zero, we determine if any single one is present.

The formula may need modification if you have criteria which can be miscounted.

For example:

Note that `Crit1` will return a match for `Crit1`, `Crit101`, etc.  Depending on your actual data, a formula modification might be possible; or a UDF might be more practical.